# error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’ when calling rclcpp::create_timer()

Tags: ros, ros2, c++, rclcpp, timer

I am trying to convert a piece of code written in ROS1 to ROS2. I am having trouble with the following line, which instantiates a `ros:::Timer` object:

in ROS1:

```
timer_ = control_nh_.createTimer(ros::Duration(1.0), 
    boost::bind(&Robot::feedbackHandle, this, _1, handle));
```

Which I tried to covert to ROS2 like this:

```
std::function<void(const std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ServerGoalHandle<control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory>>)> 
callback_func1 = std::bind(&Robot::feedbackHandle, this, handle);
timer_ = rclcpp::create_timer(control_nh_, control_nh_->get_clock(), 
rclcpp::Duration(1, 0), callback_func1);
```

However I get the following error:

```
.../robot.cpp:159:34:   required from here
/opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/create_timer.hpp:44:60: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
   44 |   auto timer = rclcpp::GenericTimer<CallbackT>::make_shared(
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   45 |     clock,
      |     ~~~~~~                                                  
   46 |     period.to_chrono<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(),
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~           
   47 |     std::forward<CallbackT>(callback),
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                      
   48 |     node_base->get_context());
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                               
/opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/create_timer.hpp:44:60: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’
/opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/create_timer.hpp:44:60: note: invalid template non-type parameter
/opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/create_timer.hpp: In instantiation of ‘rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr rclcpp::create_timer(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface>, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeTimersInterface>, rclcpp::Clock::SharedPtr, rclcpp::Duration, CallbackT&&, rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr) [with CallbackT = std::function<rclcpp_action::GoalResponse(const std::array<unsigned char, 16>&, std::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory_Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >)>&; rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::TimerBase>; rclcpp::Clock::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Clock>; rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::CallbackGroup>]’:
/opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/create_timer.hpp:64:22:   required from ‘rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr rclcpp::create_timer(NodeT, rclcpp::Clock::SharedPtr, rclcpp::Duration, CallbackT&&, rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr) [with NodeT = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node>; CallbackT = std::function<rclcpp_action::GoalResponse(const std::array<unsigned char, 16>&, std::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory_Goal_<std::allocator<void> > >)>&; rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::TimerBase>; rclcpp::Clock::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Clock>; rclcpp::CallbackGroup::SharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::CallbackGroup>]’
```

I coudln't find anything resembling this error while searching, can anyone help me understand what I did wrong?

Here are the declarations of the function that I'm trying to bind:

```
    void feedbackHandle(const std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ServerGoalHandle<control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory>> handle);
    rclcpp_action::GoalResponse moveHandle(const rclcpp_action::GoalUUID &uuid, std::shared_ptr<const control_msgs::action::FollowJointTrajectory::Goal> goal);
```

Thanks in advance.